# Tengo un error en procesar cubo olap 2019

Tags: vscode, mysqldb

Me sale error cuando intento procesar un cubo olap Gravedad Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
La base de datos no tiene dimensión de tiempo. Considere la posibilidad de crearla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error se debia al menos en mi caso por que no usaba un usuario de inicio local, se soluciono creando un usuario local